# Solar powered quarry in Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-industrialcraft

I am trying to build a quarry in Tekkit 3.1, but I am unable to figure out how to power it if I want to use solar panels.

Basically, nothing I try seems to give it power.

I've found a bunch of tutorials on YouTube, but they all seem to use some kind of "Electrical Engine", which seems to no longer be in the game. Is this no longer possible?

If it is possible, how should I go about connecting my solar panels to my quarry?

I have set up a few batboxes and they're completely full from being charged by the solar panels, what to do next?

Comment: @RonanForman I don't think that edit works. If he was working with just BuildCraft, the correct answer would be "Solar? WTF are you talking about?". Also, it basically makes my answer say "install this other mod here", but since he's using Tekkit he already has it.

Comment: @lunboks This problem isn't exclusive to technic pack players, is about Buildcraft and IC2, him acquiring the mods through the technic pack is irrelevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solar panels you're using produce EU (Industrial-Craft Energy Units), but what the Quarry needs is MJ (BuildCraft Minecraft Joule).

The Electrical Engine is part of the Forestry mod, which is no longer part of Tekkit for some reason or another. It performed that necessary conversion from EU to MJ.

There is another block that does this, though! It's called an **Energy Link**, courtesy of the [Power Converters mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/119361-132-tehkrushs-mods-timber-updated/#power), and it's a bit expensive.

[image: Energy Link recipe]

It accepts EU from your solar panels and produces BuildCraft energy. Simply wire it up, and connect it to your quarry. You can place it directly next to the quarry, but if you don't, you need at least two pieces of conductive pipe (wooden, then normal) to connect it.

A quarry needs 22 EU/t to run at full efficiency. However, if you use conductive pipes, the Energy Link will drain a whopping 72 EU/t. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if it's just that the Energy Link can't tell how much MJ the conductive pipes are going to need. Anyway, you should really place the link directly next to the quarry.

Another thing about it is that you can give the Energy Link a Redstone signal, which makes it stop converting energy. This allows you to turn the quarry on and off (with some delay though, the quarry has an internal energy storage).

(Note that if you're playing Tekkit **Lite**, this block does not exist. However, you have access to several engines that can indirectly be powered by sunlight. Namely, the 4 different Electric Engines that run off EU – effectively replacing the one from Forestry – and the Blulectric Engine from RedPower that runs off blutricity.)

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that BuildCraft ran on Michael Jackson. The more you know!

Comment: @JakeKing: I like the Mega Joule better, considering it would be about 0.28kWh. Makes the machines look more powerful.

Comment: You can now install Forestry with Tekkit or Technic, just add it like any mod pack. Electrical engine is still there.

Comment: @HubertKario The original BuildCraft author calls it Minecraft Joule (in the [BuildCraft handbook](http://www.lulu.com/shop/spacetoad/buildcraft-handbook/ebook/product-17543829.html)), so I guess that's official.

Comment: @lunboks: yeah, I know that. Anyway, as long as you remember that it's a unit of pneumatic energy it's not important how you call it...

Answer (score 0):

In Tekkit Lite this is achievable, the advantage of this approach being that you won't have to worry about fuel.

Put the following modules in a stack.  Make sure to connect the MFE's output to the LV transformer' input!  From top to bottom you have:

1. MV Solar Array (expensive but required to generate enough charge to last all night)
2. MFE (stores the charge so the quarry can mine all night)
3. LV Transformer (so the MFE won't blow up the BatBox)
4. BatBox (to limit the current output to 32 EU/t)
5. IC2 LV Consumer (converts EU for Energy Bridge)
6. Energy Bridge
7. BC Producer (converts energy to MJ for Quarry)

Now simply place the quarry adjacent to the BC Producer, and it will power up and start quarrying.  A wooden transport pipe can be stuck into the top of the quarry, and it will start spitting out items without the need for an engine to power the pipe.

The only downside I can see is that when it rains it can stop production for a bit, but the MFE and BatBox have a pretty good surplus of charge, especially if you let them fill completely before adding the quarry.

Answer (score 0):

Transformer mod, add it in to Tekkit Lite or any buildcraft world with industrial craft
electric engines and pneumatic generators

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to give further details and explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Combustion engines run my quarry fine from solar energy.  Haven't calculated numbers, but 4 engines run a 64 x 64 quarry just well enough to get it through the night.

However, combustion engines tend to explode easier if you don't pay attention to then for extended periods of time.

Answer (score -1):

In the new Tekkit Lite which is new to the Technic Pack, there are Solar Engines. I have not quite figured out how to use them, but they could probably power a quarry somehow.

Comment: Nope, they're cart modules.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is [electric engines](http://tekkitlite.wikia.com/wiki/Electric_Engines), you can feed your EU into electric engines that can drive your quarry.

Comment: He needs to add more details.

Comment: Forestry and its Electrical Engines are not available in that version of Tekkit. The question even mentions that.